# Implicit Line conversion feature in VS 2012

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

How do I disable Implicit line conversions for vb.net code written in visual studio 2012 ?

Comment: Do you mean implicit line continuation?

Comment: And if you do, this was added in VS2010...

Comment: Can you explain why you would disable this feature?  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: We have our development projects migrated to VS studio 2012 and the target framework is 3.5.When we build locally, IDE implicitly adds the line continuation when the same thing is build in other environments , like with a build script it fails.Hence the need to catch this kind of errors as early as possible, by disabling it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't appear to be possible.

[Disabling Implicit Line Continuation](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3a36c205-fa56-4881-a3ec-17244e1eaf0e/disabling-implicit-line-continuation)